# c# hookinig API

Tags: c#, api, hook, easyhook

I am working on an anticheat and I would like to hook APIs like Read/WriteProcessMemory, OpenProcess and maybe some more to check if it reads or writes some data to/from the game.

But I am not that experienced programmer to do it on my own so I tried to do it via easyhook. Firstly I got the example (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking) to work. Then I tried to replace `CreateFile` by `ReadProcessMemory` but there was a line `This.Queue.Push(hProcess);`, how am I supposed to replace `hProcess` in case I am hooking `ReadProcessMemory`?

I couldn't find any other example of hooking API in C# than the one hooking `CreateFile` posted above.
Also it doesn't need to be done by easyhook if there is a simpler way.
Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. The general wisdom there is that whatever you can do on the gamer's computer, the cheat program can undo. Depending on which cheating you want to prevent, it may be easier to move some of the computation into the server (if this is a client/server game).

Comment: I am aware of it. But if it stopped like 99+% dumbs who just found a cheat on the internet then it would be success.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read all of that article but the way I understood it, the

```
  This.Queue.Push(<argument to the original function>)
```

part is for the tracing portion of his example.

If all you want to do is prevent someone from calling ReadProcessMemory then you don't need to do this and you also won't be calling the original entry point - just return FALSE to the caller.

Comment: Which argument: hProcess, lpBaseAddress, lpBuffer, nSize, lpNumberOfBytesRead? It also needs to be string, so shall I just convert IntPrt to scring?
And I don't want to disable the function. I just need to minotor if it tries to currupt the process - game.

Comment: I meant the result that you return. If all you want to do is monitor, simply call the original function, passing through all parameters.